# Unable to see collection relation in User Strapi

Tags: node.js, strapi

I want to have a relation collection in my User in Strapi. It does not work when I write in postman:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/users?populate=customers
```

How can i get my collection? :(

This is my strapi
[image]

Comment: This might be related to the current discussion regarding issues with relation population reported in Strapi v4: https://forum.strapi.io/t/discussion-regarding-default-population-of-rest/13395

Comment: Looks like a fix is on the way: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/pull/11960